# Submitting empty values in redux-form

Tags: redux-form

Is it anyway possible to submit also the empty values on a form? If not how do you properly initialize the form from state?

If it is not possible do I really need to do `aField: this.props.data.aField || ''` for every field I want to initialize? This seems like a lot of typing and repeating especially on forms which have `FormSections` and nesting.

If it would be possible I could just do something in the lines of this.

```
handleInit() {
    const { patient, initialize } = this.props;

    initialize({
        patient.aField,
        // Other fields
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is applicable to your scenario, but you can specify initial form values in the `mapStateToProps` phase:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    initialValues: { ...state.patient } // Use this property to set your initial data
  };
}
```

This is also explained here: http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/examples/initializeFromState/